# Is there a difference between "elfish" and "elvish"?

Tags: differences, adjectives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to use “Elven”, “Elvish” and “Elfic”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23970/when-to-use-elven-elvish-and-elfic)

The dictionary seems to think that they are the same. Here are their definitions:

> [**Elfish**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/elfish): elflike; elfin;
>   **Elvish**: Just provides a link to "elfish"

I know that "elvish" can also refer to the language of the elves, but what I'm asking, is there a difference between "elfish" and "elvish" in this way:

"Elfish" is like an elf, as in "elfish looking girl". But "elvish" means that something is of an elf, that is, it comes from an elf, or is an elf, i.e. "Elvish man" meaning a man whose race is that of an elf. Is there such a difference in meaning?

If that's not clear enough, something like this.

> a: That's an elfish man. Yes the one in the jacket. Small and sprightly and everything.
>   b: He's actually elvish. His father was an elf.

Comment: I've seen that, but it's not really the same as "elfish" and "elvish"

Comment: _Elvish_ derives from the plural of _elf_, _elves_.

Comment: Meaning to say that "elvish' refers to the plural of things that are elfish? like "elfish man" but "elvish men?"

Comment: In English, adjectives are always singular; you don't say "good man" and "goods men." _Elfish_ and _elvish_ could have the same meaning, or a different meaning, but they are derived from different words.

Comment: "You're not a *real* elf - you're just an Elvish impersonator!"

Comment: I'd like to reopen this question, because I although related, this is not a duplicate. Please consider before closing