# Elven or Elfin?

Tags: grammar, orthography, books

I am writing a fantasy book and am having trouble with when and how to use words such as "Elfin", "Elven", "Elfish", and "Elvish". I don't understand the difference between using a V or an F. Help?

Comment: Does it remotely matter? Just use whatever seems best. It's fantasy.

Comment: It does matter to me honestly, I'm very OCD on the topic. And I read that question and I could not find a helpful answer.

Answer (score 8):

The choice is yours:

1. If you want elves like Tolkien’s, use *Elves* and *Elven* and *Elvish*.
2. If you want elves like [Wolfe’s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_Knight), use *Aelf* (plural *Aelfe*) and *Aelfinn*.
3. If you want elves like Andrew Lang’s or Walt Disney’s, use *Elfs* and *Elfin* and *Elfish*.

The first is English, the second Nordic, and the third Tinkerbelly.

Names matter.

Comment: Thank you, this is actually very helpful since I have read many books that use both forms of the spelling and it confused me then.

Comment: "Tinkerbelly." I like it.

Answer (score 1):

(I decided to make this an actual answer instead of a comment, since the OP didn't feel it was adequately covered in the question I tagged as a duplicate, [When to use "Elven", "Elvish" and "Elfic"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23970/when-to-use-elven-elvish-and-elfic)).

Following influential author JRR Tolkien, the "v" spelling is generally considered more "serious", the "f" spelling more whimsical.  There is no difference in the grammar.

Comment: Also thank you, the characters in the book are actually meant to be serious and I would name the more whimsical characters of similar physical traits as faeries.

Answer (score 0):

V is widely accepted and used for this matter

> Elven and Elvish

Books like Lord of the Rings can be a good source as it's in the same genre you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Consistency matters here.  Whether you habitually convert the *f* to a *v* or not should tell you what to do in these circumstances.

The singular, *elf*, obviously has an *f* at the end.  If, when you use the plural, you say *elves*, then it follows that you use *elven* and *elvish*, as the *f*-alternatives break consistency.

However, if you use *elfs* as the plural, then it is best that you use *elfen* and *elfish*.  In this case, the *v*-alternatives break consistency.

Nevertheless, let us consider other words that function similarly.  Think of the word *thief*:  From it, we get the plural *thieves* (*f* converts to a *v* in the presence of a voiced suffix), the noun *thievery* (same process), the adjective *thievish* (same process), and the verb *to thieve* (this originally had a voiced suffix, which was lost as time went on; it is retained to some cases, *he thieves, thou thievest, X thieved, etc.*).  The only word related to *thief* whose *f* does not become a *v* is *theft*, and that occurs because *-t* is a voiceless, not voiced, suffix.

So, if you say *thieves*, not *thiefs*, and you say *wives*, not *wifes*, and you say *dwarves*, not *dwarfs*, it follows that you use the *v*-forms of *elf*; but the choice is up to you.  My only advice is to remain consistent.

Comment: Thank you, this makes my usage clear as I instantly transform the word elf to elves and elvish.

Comment: My initial instincts were similar to yours, but I did a little background research, and apparently the accepted plural has always been "elves" not "elfs", even prior to Tolkien popularizing "elvish" and "elven".  In other words (according to google n grams) almost no one uses "elfs" and no one ever has, even back when "elfish" and "elfin" were in common use.